# Powershell encryption error: Recovery policy configured for this system contains invalid recovery certificate

Tags: powershell, encryption

I'm trying to [encrypt files using powershell](https://blog.ipswitch.com/automating-security-controls-using-powershell-to-automate-data-encryption), using this command:

```
(Get-Item -Path MyFile.txt).Encrypt()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
(Get-Item -Path MyFile.txt).Encrypt()

Exception calling "Encrypt" with "0" argument(s): "Recovery policy configured for this system contains invalid recovery certificate.
"
At line:2 char:1
+ (Get-Item -Path MyFile.txt).Encrypt()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

What is causing this error? Why do I need a recovery certificate?

Comment: are you able to encrypt it manually without an error?

Comment: what do you mean by manual encryption?

Comment: yes.... that can rule out if its an issue on the system. determining if `EFS` encryption is enabled or not, etc, if you are able to do it manually. `right click file > advanced > encrypt contents to secure data`

Comment: I think this offer a good explanation, in case anyone stumbles onto this later on, [Trying to encrypt files and getting an error. Recovery Policy configured for this system contains invalid recovery certificate](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/420105ec-3146-4658-883b-4d54bbebb7bc/trying-to-encrypt-files-and-getting-an-error-recovery-policy-configured-for-this-system-contains?forum=winserversecurity) This error happens due to an expired Recovery Certificate